# Dump a custom variable in Bugsnag

Tags: php, bugsnag

I am trying to solve some errors on a Script piped by postfix, and when I send an error to Bugsnag I would like to send as well the raw email.
I grab the email content with

```
$handle = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email  = stream_get_contents($handle);
```

The doc says that you can add custom metaData with the `setMetaData` function, but in my case this will be true only for this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. Actually, the setMetaData method can be called at any time during the script.